# Range Query in Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I Have A Table as Shown Below

```
number    Value
 77         ss
 74         aa
 77         ww
 78         ee
 77         ii
 74         pp
```

I am writing a Range Query to get the nearest Value

```
cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE number BETWEEN -5 AND +5 ORDER BY ABS( "+inputNumber+" - number) ", null);
```

If the Input Number is 76 then I will get all the Values of 77,78,74. But I want Only Nearest Values. Here Nearest Value of 76 is 77, I want all the Values of 77 (ie 3 values in case of this table) , not the values of 74 and 78. Any one Suggest me how to update the above query. Thank u in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get what is the nearest number in the table (the one with lower absolute value after substracting) and then in the main query get the rows with this number (with the same absolute value after substracting).

```
cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table where ABS("+inputNumber+"-number)=(SELECT MIN(ABS("+inputNumber+"-number)) FROM table)", null);
```

If you only want numbers where the difference with the input is +-5 you can check that ABS(inputNumber-number) <= 5 like this:

```
cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table where ABS("+inputNumber+"-number)=(SELECT MIN(ABS("+inputNumber+"-number)) FROM table) AND ABS("+inputNumber+"-number)<=5", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the offsets -5 and +5, your range will be from 76-5= 71 to 76+5
=81. Therefore you will retrieve all values within that range.

Instead of using the range, you can try using the TOP keyword:

```
cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT TOP 3 number, Value FROM table ORDER BY ABS("+inputNumber+" - number) ", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL` you can do something like this:

```
select * from table1 where number in
(select number from
(select distinct number,number - 76 as def from table1 where number > 76 - 5
union
select distinct number,76 - number as def from table1 where number < 76 + 5)t1
where t1.def = 
(select min(def) from
(select distinct number,number - 76 as def from table1 where number > 76 - 5
union
select distinct number,76 - number as def from table1 where number < 76 + 5)t
where def >= 0));
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/aa0c1/1)